# centered fixed width layout breaking in IE6

Tags: css

I am usually using this code

```
div#wrapper{width:900px; margin: 0 auto;}

div#header{float:left; width: 900px;}

div#sidebar{float:left; width: 300px;}

div#content{float:left; width:600px;}

div#footer{float:left; width: 900px; clear:both;}
```

and I have this markup

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

somehow the layout breaks in IE6: the whole layout floats to the left!

any knowhows on this one?

**EDIT:**
layout is valid; centering works in IE7 and 8 (but breaks in quirks)

**EDIT**
here's how it looks in quirks mode
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2646ed5285.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2646ed5285.png)

Comment: Are you in quirks mode ? or standard compliant ?  body and html have width 100% ?

Comment: testing it in IE6: breaks, testing it in IE7 and 8 Quirks Mode :break, no CSS markups for body and html width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a doctype declared..

any doctype will do ..

(*checked*)

Comment: oh, I forgot to notify that the page is valid, doctype declared and all..the code given is on the layout only

Comment: @Ygam - the doctype needs to be on the very first line, before anything else, otherwise it'll trigger quirks mode

Comment: @Ygam, it works great on my system in IE 6 when i add a doctype at the top.. the moment i remove it, it gets the behaviour you mention .. Perhaps if you can provide a live example ..

Comment: http://www.thehotelinventory.com/test - here you go, a bit of markup difference but structurally, it is the same

Comment: @Ygam, if you have to support quirks mode, then add `body {text-align:center;}`.. although it would be wiser to find a solution so that you do not go in quirks mode ...

Comment: hm...that's bad...cuz it breaks in quirks mode; a colleague told me that quirks mode is like running it in IE6

Comment: @Ygam, IE6 can work in standard-compliant mode.. look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250395%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: great tip. thanks! btw, what to you use to test your site in IE6? and test it also in later versions?

Comment: @Ygam, i just have multiple computers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this styling instead, there's no reason to float anything but the side-bar, just adds more complexity to confuse IE6.

```
div#wrapper{width:900px; margin: 0 auto;}
div#header{width: 900px;}
div#sidebar{float:left; width: 300px;}
div#content{margin-left: 300px; width:600px;}
div#footer{width: 900px; clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Gaby says, a doctype will do the trick. Give this a try at the top of your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```